# UIPopoverController won't initContentViewController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm currently facing an issue with my UIPopovercontroller.

Here are the facts, I've got a class : `ImagePickerViewController` (inheriting from a BaseViewController) containing two property :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *pickerController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popOver;
```

I also apply an overlay on the pickerController which is presented like this :

`[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:NO completion:nil];`

And when I want to show an image library through a UIPopoverController on iPad :

```
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
```

I get this error :

> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason : 'the content view controller argument must be the root of its
>   associated view controller hierarchy.'

I've already seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766051/ios5-ipad-uipopovercontroller-initwithcontentviewcontroller-nsgenericexception) but it didn't really help.

So I thought that presenting pickerController made it the root by looks like it isn't.
Any help welcomed :)

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to show the same controller twice? As a main view on iPad and at the same time inside of a popover?

Comment: I pushed my pickerController with an Overlay over it. When clicking the library button, I am supposed to have a popoverController appear, but when I initialize it, I run into this error up there. Tell me if you need any more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to display the same pickerController twice, at the same time. You can't do that. Either present it as a modal view controller using `presentViewController` or present it in a popover. Don't try to do both.

To show it in the popover, start with the line you have to create the popover:

```
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
```

then call one of the two methods to present the popover:

```
[popover presentPopoverFrom.... permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I initialized another UIImagePickerController to display the popover. :)